# Find element whose text matches text clicked in list

Tags: jquery

I have a list in a side navigation bar which represents objects on a page. The headers of the objects match the titles in the list. This is illustrated in the image below:

[image]

I am trying to show-toggle these objects using jQuery so that when the user clicks on the red list item (which would be the same header title as the red page object), the corresponding page object is toggled to show or hide.

Here is my simplified code:

```
// The left navigation list
<ul>
    <li>Charity Challenge Golf Outing</li>
    <li>Spring 2014 Membership Renewal</li>
    <li>EMEA Product Launch</li>
    <li>Platinum Customer Retention Spring Offer</li>
    <li>Key Account Upsell 2014</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
// A couple of page objects
<div class="single-activity">
    <h2>Charity Challenge Golf Outing</h2>

    [...]
</div>

<div class="single-activity">
    <h2>Spring 2014 Membership Renewal</h2>

    [...]
</div>


<div class="single-activity">
    <h2EMEA Product Launch</h2>

    [...]
</div>
```

---

```
// The jQuery
$(".left-panel li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#page-content").find(".single-activity").slideToggle();
});
```

---

**Question:** I know right now why it's not working, but I'm a little unsure how to "find" the object based on the `<h2>` title. The code works to slide toggle ALL objects (since they all have the `.single-activity` class, but I only want to hide the one clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this: Get the name attribute of the element on the left side and look for the element with the same name attribute on the right side.

Comment: First, you need to add `class="left-panel"` to your unordered list.

Comment: @AdamD It's there. I just stripped it out for readability.

Comment: Then see the answer by @adeneo below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `filter()`, or the `:contains` selector :

```
$(".left-panel li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#page-content").find(".single-activity:contains("+$(this).text()+")").slideToggle();
});
```

or with `filter()` :

```
$(".left-panel li").click(function() {
    var txt = $.trim( $(this).text() );
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#page-content").find(".single-activity").filter(function() {
        return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == txt;
    }).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This works! I've never used the ":contains()" method that you did. Could you give me a quick explanation of what's going on?

Comment: @Jon - the jQuery [***DOCS***](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) does it much better than I would ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".left-panel li").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("selected");
    $("#page-content").find(".single-activity:contains(" + $this.html() + ")").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Added after adeneo, but this is correct. Upvote for your effort :)

Comment: `:` are psedo classes by jQuery to filter selection. `:content` selects elements with html equal given value. Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)